Had [satan] set [his] heart against Job?
In Job 1:8 & again in 2:3 the LORD asks [hasatan] about Job.  The verse is almost universally translated "Have [you] considered My servant Job?"  This may be influenced in part because the Latin Vulgate uses the word 'considerasti' where the Hebrew had 'samta'.
Young's literal translation is unique in that it translates this verse "Hast thou set thy heart against My servant Job?" In the Hebrew verse 'lib' (heart) is certainly in the verse as it is in verse 41:24 speaking of [leviathan's] 'lib' (heart) of stone.  Thus of course a literal translation would translate it as 'heart.'  'Samta' in Young's translation is translated 'against.'  It has the same root as the 'yasim,' the word used by the [spirit who] appears to Eliphaz & states that (God) charges (yasim) His angels with error. (Note 'yasim' & 'samta' are both from the same root Strong's # 7760. )
Consider the translation "set [thy] heart against My servant Job" is actually more accurate in context for a number of reasons.  1st [hasatan] had set [his] heart against Job as evidenced by [his] accusation against Job, that Job was a greedy mercenary servant who would curse God to His face if he weren't paid (some might say bribed.)  2nd, the LORD describes [hasatan's] actions against Job, saying "[you] moved Me against him to destroy him without cause."  So [hasatan] was against Job & wanted to destroy him.  3rd Job was a man & [hasatan] had accused all men of being at best greedy mercenary servants.  He did this in verse 2:4 when [he] stated "All that (a) man (iysh - Str 376, & the same word that is the 1st word in the Book of Job) has he will give for his life."  [hasatan] said Job would curse God because Job is a man & any, every, & all men would curse God if he weren't paid.  This is just what man is. 4th unlike Saint Raphael in the Book of Tobit (canonical for Catholics & most Christian Orthodox) whose test of Tobit was arduous & rigorous, [hasatan's] test was brutal, cruel, & ruthless; many people died including all of Job's children & they were all killed "without cause."  Consider, the case is persuasive, powerful, & compelling supporting Young's translation that the LORD was indeed asking [hasatan] had [he] set [his] heart against Job.

First, English translations of John 1:8 & 2:3 were not influenced by the Latin Vulgate; 600 years before Jerome's vulgate was the Septuagint which reads for Job 1:8 -

καὶ εἶπεν αὐτῷ ὁ Κύριος· προσέσχες τῇ διανοίᾳ σου κατὰ τοῦ παιδός μου
᾿Ιώβ, ὅτι οὐκ ἔστι κατ᾿ αὐτὸν ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς, ἄνθρωπος ἄμεμπτος,
ἀληθινός, θεοσεβής, ἀπεχόμενος ἀπὸ παντὸς πονηροῦ πράγματος; = And the
Lord said to him, "Have you diligently considered my servant Job, that
there is none like him on the earth, a man blameless, true, godly,
abstaining from everything evil?"

In Job 2:3 we have a slightly different text but very similar:

εἶπε δὲ ὁ Κύριος πρὸς τὸν διάβολον· προσέσχες οὖν τῷ θέραποντί μου
᾿Ιώβ, ὅτι οὐκ ἔστι κατ᾿ αὐτὸν τῶν ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς ἄνθρωπος ὅμοιος αὐτῷ,
ἄκακος, ἀληθινός, ἄμεμπτος, θεοσεβής, ἀπεχόμενος ἀπὸ παντὸς κακοῦ; ἔτι
δὲ ἔχετε ἀκακίας· σὺ δὲ εἶπας τὰ ὑπάρχοντα αὐτοῦ διακενῆς ἀπολέσαι. =
And the Lord said to the devil, Have you then observed my servant
Job, that there is none of [men] upon the earth like him, a harmless,
true, blameless, godly man, abstaining from all evil? and he yet
cleaves to innocence, whereas you have told [me] to destroy his
substance without cause?

Back to the Hebrew: The YLT is not always helpful and in Job 1:8 it appears a little forced (ie, overly literal) for the following reasons:

the verb שׂוּם (sum or sim) primarily means "to set" or "to place" or "to put".
the noun לֵב (leb) refers to the heart or seat of the mind and emotions
the preposition עַל (al) means "upon", "above", "over".  Only rarely could it be translated "against"

Taken together the literal phrase "set your heart upon" does not have to mean "set you heart against" but simply "set your heart upon"; that is, "have you considered", or "have you pondered".
Therefore, a more neutral translation of Job 1:8 might read (my translation):

And YHWH said to Satan, "Have you set your mind upon My servant
Job ..."

Even the YLT has something similar in Job 2:3 which reads (I agree):

And Jehovah saith unto the Adversary, 'Hast thou set thy heart unto My
servant Job ...


I'm an amateur at Ancient Hebrew but the OP is posing a familiar problem with reading idioms in translation.
This is הֲשַׂ֥מְתָּ לִבְּךָ֖=hăśamtā libbəḵā
Looking at lib, Brown-Driver-Briggs has this as sense 1c thinking/reflection. When לֵב is used with חשׁב, they're saying this is a particular idiom and there are numerous other examples. Yes lib is the heart, but for it to match our idiom "set heart against" we'd need to find that the lexicon examples all have an adversarial intent.
From a straw poll of the examples, it looks as if the intent has to be qualified by another word:-

Proverbs 16:9 - - the heart of man plans - - לֵ֣ב יְחַשֵּׁ֣ב
Genesis 6:5 - - the thoughts of man's heart were wicked - מַחְשְׁבֹ֣ת  לִבּ֔וֹ רָעַ֥ת
Proverbs 22:17 - - apply your heart to my (wise) knowledge - - וְ֝לִבְּךָ֗ תָּשִׁ֥ית לְדַעְתִּֽי   חֲכָמִ֑ים
Psalm 62:10 - - do not set your heart on them - - תָּשִׁ֥יתוּ  לֵֽב׃

This last one shows we can't assume the phrase in Job 1:8 is adversarial, since here it's the opposite - it's aspirational. And that's without a qualifier.
From here it moves to 'proving a negative' so I'll offer a brief survey of the  usages, with the disclaimer that a Semitist could do this much better. I'm just looking for adversarial intent without a qualifier and since there are a good handful of examples I'm not second-guessing the lexicon's logic (which needs to be done for this exercise to be thorough).

Psalm 140:3 - - ? ; Proverbs 16:9 - - neutral ; Genesis 6:5 - - qualified ;
Psalm 33:11 - - aspirational ; Proverbs 6:18 - - qualified ; Proverbs 19:21 - - aspirational ; Genesis 8:21 - - ? ; Proverbs 15:28 - - qualified ; Proverbs 24:2 - - qualified ; Isaiah 33:18 - - qualified ; Isaiah 59:13 - - qualified ; Psalm 49:4 - - neutral ; Isaiah 41:22 - - neutral ; Ezekiel 44:5 - - aspirational ; 1 Samuel 9:20 - - qualified ; 2 Samuel 13:20 - - neutral ; Ezekiel 40:4 - - aspirational ; Ezekiel 44:5 - - aspirational ; Exodus 9:21 - - aspirational ; 2 Samuel 18:3 - - aspirational ; Job 2:3 - - ? (the usage being studied) ; Job 34:14 - - possibly adversarial (re. God's concern for living things) ; Job 1:8 - - ? (the usage being studied) ; Psalm 62:10 - - aspirational ; Proverbs 22:17 - - aspirational ; Proverbs 24:32 - - aspirational ; Exodus 7:23 - - ? ; 1 Samuel 4:20 - - neutral ; Proverbs 27:23 - - aspirational (tend to your flocks) ; Jeremiah 31:21 - - aspirational ; Job 7:17 - - aspirational

On the whole this is a word that seems more like setting your heart "on" than "against". The only unqualified example able even to support an adversarial intention was Job 34:14 but if that's Satan mocking God it's ironically picking up the same earlier usages the OP is asking about - like "if God put his mind to it, he could really mess organic life up."
There was another recent question where YLT appeared to mistranslate something to simplify (and de-nuance?) the Satan-Job conflict.
Elihu - what is meant by דֵּעַ - 'dei' in Book of Job - knowledge or opinion?
That's only two data points but I start to wonder if there's more theological bias in play than YLT are given credit for.
Where the Vulgate has considerasti, the LXX has προσέχω= to hold to or attend to, which is again a neutral if not slightly aspirational word. πρός not ἀντί...
Job 1:8 and Job 2:3 don't have a qualifier and this is a phrase that is elsewhere used without qualification for tending to sheep, or paying attention to God's word. So "set your heart against" looks flimsy.
Have YLT disagreed with this lexicon's usages? Brown-Driver-Briggs has other usages 6b for an "evil" heart or 9b for an "anxious" heart, but these examples are all qualified. So it begins to look as if the only resemblance to "set your heart against" was the English word which is then indefensible as translation practice.
The OP presents an argument that an adversarial phrase here would cohere with the overall narrative and the established character of Satan. For all that may be true, the author didn't use one.

"The OP presents an argument that an adversarial phrase here would cohere with the overall narrative and the established character of Satan. For all that may be true, the author didn't use one."
It is true, the author(s) did not use an obvious adversarial phrase, & not being confident enough to even say I'm an amateur at Ancient Hebrew I was hoping that there might be delicate & restrained indications in the Hebrew text that might point to the animosity of [hasatan] to Job that is recognized in the LORD's question of [him].  Something an expert would recognize.

So regarding the present state of matters, I would consider Young's translation debatable from the perspective/dimension of the subject Hebrew text.  BUT the acknowledgement that it may be true that the "adversarial phrase may cohere with the overall narrative" thus supporting Young's translation, leads to another question.  How should the ambiguity be weighed versus the context?  Should the context influence the translation by resolving the ambiguity?

The word's meaning comes solely from its literary context (absent the spoken context that truly defined it). If we have to inquire from the local context for a word then we don't really know what it means and can't pretend to understand the local context either. I didn't find ambiguity in the ~31 examples: this is a word that can gain an adversarial intent by its being qualified by another word (e.g. "evil") but without one it's aspirational. Without one it's the thing one does to sheep or God's word. Quite different from our "take care of" where we'd soon turn up unqualified adversarial uses

(for completeness) a text can define a word's meaning either directly or subtly, but we'd then have to account for what techniques we think the book of Job is using to redefine לִבְּךָ֖, as well. I think there's no sign of that here, and it's the sort of common phrase that a writer usually won't try to move
